# DB2 "Triggers" on actions beyond update, insert and delete

Tags: triggers, db2, database-trigger

After researching triggers, I've only come up with thing showing how to update, insert and delete. It seems like that's even part of the syntax itself. [DB2 Docs on Triggers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/sqlp/rbafymultisql.htm)

Is there any kind of trigger, or something similar, which would let me track a larger set of actions, things like `SELECT` and `ALTER TABLE`?

We (unfortunately) share a database with some teams which we don't strictly trust to not do things like run insane `SELECT` statements (locking up the databases) or `ALTER TABLE` without us knowing. We'd like to be able to track when these happen and what user made the change.

---

Please, no suggestions recommending we get our database separated in some way. We're working towards that in the long term, but we need this in the short term.

Comment: Alwaus quote your Db2 server platform and version when asking for help. Sounds like you need to deploy WLM, if you license permits it.  For There's no trigger for SELECT. You can use the monitoring table-functions, or tools like DSM, or third party tools to see what's consuming most resources, or mine the package cache via scripting.

Comment: Thanks. We are a Fortune 100 company, so I'm sure we have a super-ultra-deluxe license. The problem is, my team doesn't directly control the database servers, so deploying new things like that can be tricky. I will look into it more though. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its borders a hate topic of trust.  We never want to see issues of trust between teams.

Comment: I could remove the bit about other teams if you think that'd make it more inappropriate. It isn't so much a matter of trust or "hate", it's a matter of protecting against accidental mistakes which everyone makes. We just want to protect against accidental mistakes that other teams may not know about or forget to share with us.

Comment: There are things like Workload Management and Audit that help with that. Look into those and open a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

The link for DB2 docs given in your post points to IBM i. Is your database DB2 for i?

For IBM i, you can use detailed database monitor to capture all SQL statements including DDL commands like alter table. However, running detailed database monitor for all users causes performance problems. 
We were in same situation as you with multiple teams using same server as database. We ended up writing custom user exits to capture all SQLs (with  user details) in our case.

Link to database monitor:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzajq/strdbmon.htm