# DB2 Get column with variable column name

Tags: sql, db2, database-trigger, db2-luw

This is an off-shoot of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48505499/db2-triggers-on-actions-beyond-update-insert-and-delete) I asked, with me trying to solve it myself.

I've figured out how to get the column names for the table I'm in (by querying `SYSCAT.COLUMNS`). I now need to someone table the value from that, and get the column with that name off of the cursor (basically, a variable column name).

For illustration, in something like JavaScript, I'd just do something like this:

```
const c = { COLNAME: 'myCol' };
const n = { myCol: '5' };
n[c.COLNAME]
```

In my cause, `c` is the cursor with the columns (with `COLNAME` the name of the column) and `n` is the row that has a column named the value of `c.COLNAME`.

If it matters, I'm doing this inside the body of a trigger.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but google "dynamic SQL"

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a dynamic SQL statement...

then `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` or `EXECUTE IMMEDIATELY` that statement...

As commented in your other post, this is a bad idea to do in a trigger..

Comment: I like  this question better because there is no Trust issue that.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I can find examples of building a dynamic SQL statement that returns a row (like a select), but can't seem to figure out how to make one that lets me have a conditional.